# pass variable though URL for getting JSON

Tags: php, android, json

I have an app which loads data from a server and publish that data in the text view but there is a scene

```
      <?php

     define('HOST','xxxxxx');
     define('USER','xxxxxxx');
     define('PASS','xxxxx');
     define('DB','xxxxxxx');



     //Connecting to Database
      $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

      $sql = "select * from Leaderboard where email='test@test.com'";

      $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      $result = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array('name'=>$row[1],
         'rank'=>$row[2],
         'accuracy'=>$row[3]));
          }
        echo json_encode (array("list"=>$result));


        mysqli_close($con);

         ?>
```

this is my PHP file which gives JSON like this

```
        {"list":[{"name":"Vipul S","rank":"1","accuracy":"80"}]}
```

and I am getting these values into my android app very easily using volley library but the thing is I need something to make that email variable dynamic because I am getting user email from users phone so I need to pass a variable to PHP through my android, so is there any chance that I can pass this through my URL which is written in android

```
 my URL is: "http://thehostels.in/judgement_files/myleaderboard.php"
```

so can I pass the emails from URL that will be taken by PHP file through

```
  $email=$_GET['userEmail'];
```

finally what I want is to that the JSON should change according to email that changes due to URL, I hope I made sense

Answer (score 1):

You can pass email id in URL as

```
http://thehostels.in/judgement_files/myleaderboard.php?userEmail=test@test.com
```

and you can use this parameter in PHP as below

```
$email = $_GET['userEmail'];
$sql = "select * from Leaderboard where email='$email'";
```

For security reason you should use proper validation for email id.